# Set shadow for Android Switch text

Tags: android

Is it possible to set shadow for text of Android Switch Widget? I tried to set shadow using XML but it doesn't work.

```
<Switch android:id="@+id/test_switch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:shadowColor="@color/text_shadow"
            android:shadowDx="-1"
            android:shadowDy="-1"
            android:shadowRadius="1" />
```

Also ON and OFF states have different colors. Is it possible to set different shadow colors for different states? (Maybe programmatically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked code of Switch Widget and found that android:shadowColor, android:shadowDx, android:shadowDy, android:shadowRadius attributes don't affect shadow of on/off label. So the answer is "no".